# R pasting character vector within emmeans

Tags: r, vector, character, emmeans

I have a fairly large list of variables that I want to collapse across for estimating marginal means via emmeans. I'd like to list these out once to keep the analytic code more clean. Here's a sample:

```
covs_mrg <- c("male", "race4", "unemployable")
```

Then i'd like to just be able to refer to covs_mrg where it says nuisance = like:

```
mrg_mns <- emmeans(emp6mos_out, ~ tx, type='response', nuisance = c("male", "race4", "unemployable")
```

I've tried using the following, but emmeans doesn't seem to recognize it:

```
covs_mrg <- paste("c(", paste(shQuote(c("male", "race4", "unemployable") ), collapse=", "),")")
```

I've even tried wrapping the result within as.formula(), but that didn't seem to work either.  Any help is appreciated!

Comment: The input for `nuisance` seems to be a vector, so why not use `nuisance = covs_mrg`

Comment: I meant `covs_mrg <- c("male", "race4", "unemployable")` and not the pasted one

Comment: Well i feel silly...i was so caught up in the weeds i made it more difficult than it needed to be. Sorry for the wasted post!

Comment: Keep in mind that any nuisance variables that interact with other variables in the model (even other nuisance variables) are silently ignored. And that you'll get the same result, albeit less efficiently, if you omit the nuisance speak.

Comment: @RussLenth Can you say more about what you mean by 'omit the nuisance speak'?
Also, i have been reviewing the emmeans documentation.  Can you point me to where i might find more about the MODE feature when working with count/zero-inflated outcomes?

Comment: Oops, meant nuisance *spec* -- i.e., just don't specify `nuisance` at all. Must have been auto-incorrect

Comment: The ["models" vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/models.html) shows what options are available for what models. Unfortunately, for zero-inflated models, there is little support except for the separate component and ZI parts.

Comment: @RussLenth if i omit the nuisance portion of the call to emmeans, i get an error that the rows of the reference grid exceed the limit (by alot since i have a large dataset and a large number of predictors). My model includes a treatment indicator (of primary interest) and a large number of covariates i'm 'controlling for'.

Comment: OK, well in that case, you need it, and that's why it exists. For most situations, it only affects efficiency.